# Parse database value in selection tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I want get value from a database to a SELECTION box by changing another SELECTION box.

For example by changing "company" selection tag.
The value will send onChange to a PHP file.
After then i want get the value from that php file in to "f_name" Selection tag.

```
<select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">
        <?php  
        $dbg=$con->db;
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `company_table`";
        $stmt=$dbg->query($sql);
        foreach($stmt as $row) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['company_id'];?>" ><?php echo $row['company_name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>

      </select>
      <select class="form-control" id="f_name" name="f_name">

      </select>
```

onChange code for the "Company" Selection tag is following:

```
 $('#company').on("change", function() {
      var company_id=$(this).val();
       $.post('db/project_add_to_workers_db.php',// location
              {'action':'GetRow','company_id':company_id},// form name or data 
              function (data){// return function note 'date' is user define
                  alert (data);
                  var jsonData = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem("data"));
                  var $select = $('#f_name');
                  $(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
                      var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.f_name).text( o.l_name);
                      $select.append($option);
                  });
              }); 
          });
```

Comment: You're on the half way, now create a PHP script to get the `company` id and return your desired values. You're already creating the second select, what is your problem actually?

Comment: Looking now at your code, you have a syntax error on the closing `function (data){` annon function, it should be only `}` and not `});`